# How do I reply to an email in CiviCRM (Activity or CiviCase)

Tags: email

I have CiviCRM set up to import e-mails that are sent to our main support desk.  These e-mails come in as "Inbound Email" activity types.  At this time we are manually importing those e-mails into a CiviCase case to keep track of them.

My question is how do you reply to these emails?  When I look at the activity itself, it does not have an option to reply.  When I connect the inbound email activity to a Case, I can compose a new email as an action in the case, but I still don't have an option to reply to an email.

By "reply to an email" what I am looking for is to have a new email window opened, with the email I am replying to already in the email compose window and quoted, and the subject set, and the "to" and "cc" lines set, so that I am all ready to compose a reply.

Is this possible?  Or is there an extension to support this?  It seems like such a basic function I'm really confused that I don't see it.

Thank you